# How to locally trigger aws Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-edge, aws-iot-greengrass

I have a Greengrass Core device and on it I deployed a simple Lambda function but I don't know how to locally trigger it. Is it even possible?

I am looking for a command line call, something like this: "aws lambda invoke --function-name my-math-function --payload '{"action": "square","number": 3}' output.txt" but this one triggers a lambda function that is defined in the cloud. I want to trigger my locally running lambda (deployed as a component in greengrass).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage AWS Greengrass Lambda functions with AWS Serverless Application Model(SAM). Please refer to the link here: [Managing Greengrass Lambda Code With AWS SAM](https://www.trek10.com/blog/sam-greengrass-lambda-update)

You can invoke your function locally by using the [sam local invoke](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-invoke.html) command

Comment: Great, glad that it worked for you. Can you accept is as an answer?